# KineticJs not redrawing entire stage

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I'm using stage.draw() to update the canvas. Somehow the entire canvas is not cleared between the draws. If a handle happens to be located outside the "invisible box" I can't manipulate it.

http://snag.gy/MJXfq.jpg

The fraction redrawn is proportional to the window size.

EDIT: 
It did not work. Perhaps it's something with my window-resize function. Here is a (malfunctioning jsfiddle).

```
var adaptScreen = function () {
    //console.log("Resizing window");
    var w = document.body.clientWidth || document.width;
    var h = document.body.clientHeight || document.height;

    viewModel.width = w;
    viewModel.height = h;

    updateStage();
    updateBackground();
    updateGraph();
    updateCircleHandles();

    redraw();
}

/**
* Setup the KineticJS Stage
*/
    addStage = function () {
        stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 100000,
        height: 23
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8CSfr/6/

Comment: Try calling .draw on your layer(s) and not the stage.  If that doesn't work we'll need to see some code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this could be a recently fixed bug related to the browser's zoom setting. If so, make sure you are using the latest version of KineticJS.